# Char (hex representation) from NSString

Tags: objective-c, c, character-encoding, nsstring, character-arrays

I have a C char array in iOS that looks like this:

```
static char aStr[MY_STRING_LENGTH] = {0xc0,0xa7,0x82};
```

When I inspect it on the console (p aStr), I get output that looks like:

```
(char [MY_STRING_LENGTH]) $1 = "\xc0\xa7\x82"
```

and that is all fine.  However, I need to put that original string in a plist, and read it in as config data.  If I type my entry in the plist as a NSString, how can I get the C char array out with the same values?  So far, everything I have tried seems to translate the hex values into something else.

I have tried things like:

```
NSString *newStr = [stringFromPlist UTF8String];
```

Or breaking the NSString into an array with:

```
NSArray *arr = [stringFromPlist componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

and then iterating and converting with:

```
char newArr[MY_STRING_LENGTH];

for (int i = 0; i < MY_STRING_LENGTH; i++) {
    newArr[i] = [arr[i] UTF8String];
}
```

but so far nothing seems to do what I need.  I keep ending up with values in the char array that contain the "0x" instead of the "\x".

My C chops are FAR too rusty for this, so I am hoping someone can point out my error.

Cheers!

Comment: I do not fully understand what you are trying to do. What is `stringFromPlist`? Do you want to convert `aStr` to an NSString? What is the intended result? (Note that C0 A7 82 is not a valid UTF-8 sequence.)

Comment: Hi Martin, stringFromPlist is an NSString read from a plist.  Just a var holding an instance of NSString.  What I need to do is take the NSString representation of the char[] (i.e. {0xc0,0xa7,0x82}) and be able to read it from a NSString (i.e. @"0xc0,0xa7,0x82") such that it results in a char array looking like \xc0\xa7\x82.  Clear as mud, right?  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a more elegant solution, but you could try:

```
NSString *stringFromPlist = @"0xc0,0xa7,0x82";
NSArray *arr = [stringFromPlist componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
char newArr[MY_STRING_LENGTH];
for (int i = 0; i < MY_STRING_LENGTH; i++) {
    unsigned result = 0;
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:arr[i]];
    [scanner scanHexInt:&result];
    newArr[i] = result;
}
```

Comment: There may be a more elegant solution, but I will take one that works right now.  Cheers, Reinhard!

Comment: Glad that I could help you! Happy programming!